# Type casting object to child class object

Tags: c++, casting, virtual, virtual-inheritance, typecasting-operator

I want to cast object hlaObj to HlaObject from  RtiValueAggregate but it's not working...! There is no inheritance between two classes. and HlaObject is virtually derived from RtiValue.
can anyone tell me whats wrong with the following code:
Thanks!

```
class RtiValue;
class HlaObject;

class RtiValueAggregate 
{
public:
    friend class RtiValue;
    int w;

    RtiValueAggregate() : w(10)
    {        
    }

};


class RtiValue
{
public:
    friend class RtiValueAggregate;

    RtiValue()
    {
        int x = 5;
        pAggregate_ = new RtiValueAggregate();
    }

    RtiValueAggregate* getAggregate() const
    {
        return pAggregate_;
    }

private:
    RtiValueAggregate* pAggregate_;
};


class ObjectAttribute : public RtiValue
{
public:
    int v;

    ObjectAttribute() : v(0)
    {
        RtiValue();
    }        

};


class HlaObject :public virtual RtiValueAggregate
{
public:
    int a;
    ObjectAttribute* ptrV;

    HlaObject() : a(1)
    {
        ptrV = new ObjectAttribute();
    }

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    RtiValue *rtiVal = new RtiValue();
    RtiValueAggregate* rtiValueAggr = rtiVal->getAggregate();
    HlaObject *hlaObj = reinterpret_cast<HlaObject*>(rtiValueAggr);

    cout << "Press any key to exit..." << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `it's not working`. Look at the error messages, they should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: What builder are you using? I built it with `g++` and no error is dumped. On the other hand, do you use multiple inheritance in another part of the code? Otherwise, I don't see the need of using virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dynamic_cast`, never use `reinterpret_cast`.

BTW, why are doing:

```
class HlaObject :public virtual RtiValueAggregate
```

And not:

```
class HlaObject :public RtiValueAggregate
```